# .NET MVC - How to assign a class to Html.LabelFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This code

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) %>
```

produces this

```
<label for="Name">Name</label>
```

But I want this

```
<label for="Name" class="myLabel">Name</label>
```

How do you do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, looking at the source (System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.cs) for this method, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with an HtmlHelper in ASP.NET MVC 2. I think your best bet is to either create your own HtmlHelper or do the following for this specific label:

```
<label for="Name" class="myLabel"><%= Model.Name %></label>
```

Comment: It doesn't work

 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But perhaps that's another error. I'm just really new to MVC. So there is no way to put css class into Html.LabelFor, alright, thanks Richard!

Comment: Do what Richard suggested, just create your own HtmlHelper overload of LabelFor(). You can copy the syntax of the LabelFor() source code if you're not sure how to build the expression signature.

Comment: Hi Nathan, how do you create an overload for LabelFor? Or where can I copy it from? You can post it as a new answer, thanks.

Comment: Just fyi, I know why Model.Name doesn't work. It's because I am adding a new item, so Model (the Item) is still null.

Answer (score 142):

Sadly, in [MVC 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) the Html.LabelFor() method has no method signatures that permit a direct class declaration. However, [MVC 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) adds 2 overloads that accept an htmlAttributes anonymous object.

As with all HtmlHelpers it's important to remember that the C# compiler sees `class` as reserved word.

So if you use the @ before the class attribute it works around the problem, ie:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhysicalPostcode, new { @class= "SmallInput" })
```

The @ symbol makes the "class" a literal that is passed through.

Comment: Why isn't this upvoted more? It works perfectly! (In MVC4, at least.)

Comment: I tried in MVC 3, it does not seem to like it...maybe MVC4 FTW!

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm using MVC4 btw :)

Comment: Perhaps edit this question/answer to indicate that MVC4 solves the problem

Comment: This syntax also works for the `@Html.Label` helper in Razor Web Pages.

Answer (score 66):

Overload of LabelFor:

```
public static class NewLabelExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return LabelFor(html, expression, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("label");
        tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        tag.Attributes.Add("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));
        tag.SetInnerText(labelText);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/03/asp-net-mvc-labelfor-helper-with-htmlattributes.aspx

Comment: Like a Nathan Taylor says, and for aximili