# Html.LabelFor not rendering HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am binding a model to view.

```
public class Validation
{
   [Display("Please enter in <h5>day(s)</h5>")]
   public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Here `Message` property will be set as `Please enter in <h5>day(s)</h5>`.

In view am binding model property to `LabelFor`.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
```

Expecting output as

```
Please enter in day(s)
```

But actual output is

```
Please enter in <h5>day(s)</h5>
```

I want part of the string to vary in size and cosmetics, so applying CSS to the entire label is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Please check now. I missed `DataAnnotations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your display string `"<h5>some text</h5>"` will be rendered as text, not HTML. MVC will encode the `<` `>` characters to `&lt;` `&gt;`, causing them to be displayed as-is.

You shouldn't want to do this like this anyway.

The proper way would be to apply the display string to contain the text you want:

```
[Display("some text")]
```

Then create a CSS class:

```
label.fancyLabel {
    /* your style here that makes a label look like a h5 */
}
```

Then apply that class to the label (from [.NET MVC - How to assign a class to Html.LabelFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294250/net-mvc-how-to-assign-a-class-to-html-labelfor)):

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message, new { @class= "fancyLabel" })
```

As for your edit, if you want to just render the `Display` attribute's text as literal HTML, you'll have to:

- Introduce your own HTML helper.
- In there, write a label (and make sure to set the `for=` attribute).
- Read the DisplayAttribute's value.
- `@Html.Raw()` that value as the label text.
- Use `@Html.YourLabelHelper(m => m.Message)` to render it.

But using HTML on your models like that isn't really advisable. Views and templates should decide how to render a model, not the other way around.

Comment: I am aware of this. But I am in a need to render as actual HTML. Is that possible?